# custom dropdown filter and bootstrap-table pagination refresh

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I added custom drop down filter to my bootstrap-table.

**Problem;** When I'm selecting option from this filter and amount of records is changing I still can see same unchanged pagination figures.

Filter was added to bootstrap-table via `data-toolbar="#key_filter"`

**Question**
Is there any simple way to link this custom drop-down with pagination to have same result like for search which is in bundle with bootstrap-table.

HTML:

```
<div id="key_filter">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Filter records by status <span
            class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu alertFilter" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li id="keySuccess"><a href="#"><strong>Success</strong></a></li>
        <li id="keyDanger"><a href="#"><strong>Danger</strong></a></li>
        <li id="keyWarning"><a href="#"><strong>Warning</strong></a></li>
        <li id="keyAll"><a href="#"><strong>Display All</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<table id="tbl" data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true"
   data-page-list="[10, 20, 50, 100, All]" data-classes="table table-hover"
   data-toolbar="#key_filter" data-show-pagination-switch="true">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th data-sortable="true">Phone of...</th>
    <th data-sortable="true">Reason</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="warning" data-ss-key="warning">
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>phone1</td>
    <td>why warning ?</td>
</tr>
<tr class="success" data-ss-key="success">
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>phone1</td>
    <td>why warning ?</td>
</tr>
<tr class="danger" data-ss-key="danger">
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>phone1</td>
    <td>why warning ?</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
        $('#keySuccess').click(function () {
            $("tr[data-ss-key]").hide();
            superText = $('#keySuccess').text();
            $('#dropdownMenu1').html(superText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#dropdownMenu1').css('background','#03a678');
            $("tr[data-ss-key=success]").show();
        });
        $('#keyDanger').click(function () {
            $("tr[data-ss-key]").hide();
            superText = $('#keyDanger').text();
            $('#dropdownMenu1').html(superText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#dropdownMenu1').css('background','#ef4836');
            $("tr[data-ss-key=danger]").show();
        });
        $('#keyWarning').click(function () {
            $("tr[data-ss-key]").hide();
            superText = $('#keyWarning').text();
            $('#dropdownMenu1').html(superText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#dropdownMenu1').css('background','#f39c12');
            $("tr[data-ss-key=warning]").show();
        });
        $('#keyAll').click(function () {
            superText = $('#keyAll').text();
            $('#dropdownMenu1').html('Filter supervisions by status'+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#dropdownMenu1').css('background','none');
            $("tr[data-ss-key]").show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `load` method of bootstrapTable in your case:

```
$table.bootstrapTable('load', filterData);
```

The best way is that you can use the `requestParams` to filter your request params, for example like: `http://your-url?type=success`, and return data what you want.

Write you a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3567/

Comment: Thanks. It is Woking well now.